# How to implement showDialog that depends on an FutureNotifier.family (Riverpod)

Tags: flutter, riverpod, riverpod-generator, riverpod-annotation

Im trying to show a dialog in a onPressed of a button. The dialog has 2 buttons, one of which calls a FutureNotifier.family. Whats the right way to do this?

I can’t find anything on what would be the correct way of doing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.